# Django ORM: See if a model has no foreign key entry in another model

Tags: django, django-orm

So , I have this 2 models:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
```

and another one:

```
class SiteInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

Is there a way to get the Sites that have no entry in the SiteInfo ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Site.objects.filter(siteinfo__isnull=True)`

Comment: I don't have the code now next to me to test your idea, but I see that you flter all Sites that have the site column as null... So I presume that you meant SiteInfo.

Comment: I need every entry in SiteInfo to have a site correlation. I'm interested to find out which Sites have no SiteInfo defined yet. Will your suggestion work for this ?

Comment: I misread you question. :-) Here's correct solution. "To refer to a "reverse" relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model". [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: That sounds more like it! Didn't know about this. I'll test it as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: I had to add `.distinct()` as I would get duplicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic way to find the list of all reverse relations of a model.

```
reverse_model_array = [f.related_model for f in model._meta.get_fields() 
if f.auto_created and not f.concrete]
```

This will list all the models that have reference to this model(foreign key, many to many key, etc)

Answer (score -4):

I think this will working, but not so efficient:

with_no_site_info = [site for site in Site.objects.all() if site.site_infos_set.all().count() == 0]

Comment: I agree with DrTyrsa on this one. If I have 1000+ Sites, it will blow by server with queries.

Comment: "I think this will working, but not so efficient:" I said this before I wrote it, Thinking that you have 1000- Sites.

Comment: I understand. Thank you anyway for your idea ;)