# Django: Check for related objects and whether it contains data

Tags: python, django

For example, I have two models in a car management system(webpage):

```
    class Brand(models.Model):
        brand_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    class Cars(models.Model):
        car_model= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
        car_production_year= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
        car_brand= models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
```

Now, I want to delete a Brand data from the car system. How can I check if this Brand has been used in another model or does that foreign key contains any data(as I have allowed null True for car_brand in Cars model).

**PS:** 
using this function:

```
self.model._meta.get_all_related_objects():
```

I got any related object in used in Brand model class. But, I don't know how to get if that related object contains any data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `exists()`. It's designed to be used for exactly this type of situations:

```
for brand in Brand.objects.all():
    if not brand.cars_set.all().exists():
        # delete
```

Also it's almost always faster than any other type of check because of the way it is designed to work at the database level. You can read details of `exists()` behaviour in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I was looking for something dynamic, like I want to override the delete operation( def delete(self): ) and catch the model which is going to be deleted has any active related object. If do, raise an exception, else delete.

Comment: You can do this with the same logic as I posted in my answer. But instead of overriding `delete()` use [pre_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete) and [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete) signals on your Brand model because `delete()` method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet.

Comment: Is the same doing `query_set.all().exists()` than `query_set.exists()`?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, I just used `all()` to show that you can put something else between queryset and `exists()`, for example `filter()`

Comment: How do we get all the relational fields on the model to check if they exist?

Answer (score 10):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094835/django-orm-see-if-a-model-has-no-foreign-key-entry-in-another-model), for my code, this was faster:

```
for b in Brand.objects.filter(cars__isnull=True):
    # delete
```

If You have the ids (my case), I used this (60% faster than cars_set):

```
for brand_id in brand_id_set:
    if Brand.objects.filter(id=brand_id).filter(cars__isnull=True):
        # delete
```

I am using Django 1.11

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the easiest way is like so:

```
# brand is an instance of Brand

if not brand.cars_set.all():
    # delete
else:
    # do something else
```

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) cover foreign keys in quite a lot of detail.

Comment: Using `all()` makes even more sense in templates. When you don't want to output anything when no related objects exists. `{% with model.rmodel_set as rmodels %}{% if rmodels %}<table>{% for rmodel in rmodels %}<tr><td>...{% endfor %}</table>{% endif %}{% endwith %}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cars_with_brands = Car.objects.filter(car_brand__isnull = False)
if cars_with_brands.count() == 0:
    # you can delete Brand Model
else:
   cars_with_brands.delete()
   # you can delete Brand Model
```